# Send HTML email in Outlook 2010 - no 'Insert as Text' option?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I am trying to send an HTML email via Outlook 2010 using the 'Attach File' option, on several articles it says there should be an 'Insert at Text' option but I only seem to have an 'Open' option, does anyone know why it is not showing correctly for me?

Comment: Do you mean that you couldn't attach a file to your HTML email?

Comment: I don't have the option to change to 'Insert as Text', just open and that only attaches it to the email, not within the body of the email.

Comment: When you click on "New Email" to write your email, you should find Insert tab that has all you need

Comment: But the attach file option doesn't have the 'Insert as Text' option I need to use to include the HTML element in the body of my email,  I am trying to find out why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding it as well. Found the steps online so i will replicate it here for you. Click on the button on the top after the undo button (looks like an inverted eject button) and choose `More Commands`

[image]

Once the window is open, look for attachments. If you are not able to find it, change the dropdown above it `Choose commands from:` to find it. Once found add to the right side of the screen and press ok.
[image]

Now the attachment icon will be visible on the top ribbon. Now you should be able to see the `Insert as Text` option when you want to insert a HTML template.

[image]

Hope the above steps is the answer you were after.

Since you are creating emails, just a quick note:

1. Media queries will not work when you send emails thru outlook. Outlook has a habit of stripping it out completely.
2. Web fonts will not work. Strips it out as well.

Cheers

Comment: I still get the same thing, I will have to speak to my IT department as something clearly seems to be wrong!